# Writing to csv breaks string to characters

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write into a csv file, I have a hard coded header that I want to write:

```
head = ["Q151", "item time", "deliberativness", "deliberativness time",
        "Q153", "item time", "deliberativness", "deliberativness time"]
```

But when I run the csv writer it is inserting every char into a different column, and every item in the list to a different row. so I am getting

```
Q 1 5 1 
i t e m t i m e
```

and not `Q151 item time ...`

```
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for r in head:
        writer.writerow(r)
```

I am using a simple `writer` like in the python docs. What am I doing wrong?

excepted result as I said above Q151 item time ...

Comment: You should pass your row to the method and not every item

Comment: What is `first_row`?

Comment: Can you write the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code

```
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(first_row)
```

Writer iterate your variable and write each element to the next cell.
When you give it string value, writer iterate it.
So to write all the lines you could add a loop.

```
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(first_row)
    list_of_rows = [['1', '2', '3'], ]
    for row in list_of_rows:
         writer.writerow(row)
    # but better to use writerows
    writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You can use the for loop when you have a list of lists/rows, and you want to wirte those into your file:

```
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, fieldnames=head)
    writer.writeheader()
```

Comment: What about the data row?

Comment: also what is fieldname, is it in python 2.7?

Comment: That's how to pass the header row. Alternatively, you can use `writer.writerow(head)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! You simply just put the string in a list:
`write.writerow([string])`

For example:

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'a') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerow([string])
```